# Bulk User Creation in OwinContext (Performance)

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity, bulk

I am uploading a excel file containing all required users into my website using ASP.NET Identity and OwinContext and EF 6.
My code looks like below:

```
foreach (var bulkUserDetail in bulkUser.BulkUserDetails)
{

        var userManager = owinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        var userProfile = new UserProfile();

        userProfile.Username = bulkUserDetail.Username;


        AspNetUser newUser = new AspNetUser
        {
            UserName = userProfile.Username,
            Email = bulkUserDetail.Email,
            LastPasswordChangedDate = null,
        };

        var creationResult = userManager.Create(newUser);

        if (creationResult.Succeeded)
        {

            string token = userManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(newUser.Id);

        }

}
```

The issue is that the performance of following two lines is pretty disappointing

```
userManager.Create(newUser) -- (900 milliseconds)
userManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(newUser.Id)      --(1800 milliseconds)
```

In large quantity, i.e 2000 users, the performance become a serious issue.
Is there better a practice to speed up this process? I am open to suggestions but I have to keep the OwinContext library.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For one thing you're re-getting the UserManager INSIDE of your loop.  Is that really necessary?  I haven't looked at the code but if there's any lazy loading that is occurring, it could be slowing things down.

Comment: Thanks David. It helped a lot. I also used one Context object for the whole upload block and it improved the performance too. Now it loads the 2000 records in around 20 minutes. Any other idea?

Comment: after taking some time to look through the source, I think you're out of luck if you're dead set on using ApplicationUserManager.  There's just nothing that supports any sort of chained context or batch user creation.  Your best bet is probably some sort of parallelization (like suggested below) although that may not necessarily give you any better results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the user creation inside a parallel for which might speed up the overall time, however there is an issue with this:

- The call to `Create` and `GeneratePasswordResetToken` are slow because they call the database
- Doing the work in parallel would increase the number of concurrent calls to the database potentially slowing it down even more, this really depends on how good the hardware hosting your database is.

  ```
  var userManager = owinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

  Parallel.ForEach (bulkUser.BulkUserDetails, bulkUserDetail => 
  {       
      //Do you really need to make this userProfile as its not used
      var userProfile = new UserProfile();

      userProfile.Username = bulkUserDetail.Username;

      AspNetUser newUser = new AspNetUser
      {
          UserName = userProfile.Username,
          Email = bulkUserDetail.Email,
          LastPasswordChangedDate = null,
      };

      var creationResult = userManager.Create(newUser);

      if (creationResult.Succeeded)
      {

          string token = userManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(newUser.Id);

      }
  })
  ```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have thought about Parallel before and unfortunately the OwinContext and EF6 are not very happy with multiple threads or maybe I was doing it wrong!